# Salesforce CPQ custom calculation based on custom fields

Tags: custom-field, custom, cpq, pricerule

Does anyone know how to use custom fields of a custom object in a price rule? For example, I have the `Living Area` number field. If someone now clicks on “Calculate”, the number of products should simply be multiplied by the number in the `Living Area` field.

Comment: Is the custom object related to the Quote object in some way? How would the quote be related to the record on the custom object that has the `Living Area` field?